# Unable to add index files to solr from nutch

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

I have setup nutch(1.4) with solr(4.4.0) on windows and have crawled the nutch default pages mentioned in the tutorial. However after the crawl is successful I am unable to add the pages to the index using the command "**bin/nutch solrindex http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/***"

Following is the extract from the hadoop logs. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
2013-09-13 14:50:24,137 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter
2013-09-13 14:50:24,137 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off
2013-09-13 14:50:24,137 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: site dest: site
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id
2013-09-13 14:50:24,215 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url
2013-09-13 14:50:24,277 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Adding 11 documents
2013-09-13 14:50:24,511 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error

Internal Server Error

request: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:49)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.close(SolrWriter.java:93)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
2013-09-13 14:50:25,229 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

Comment: Please add your solr logs too.

Answer (score 0):

with this information, I think you forget to run Solr or you didn't get the access permission to nutch!
do you have access to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/solr/` in your browser?